# Faster way to write this rake command - rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

Every time I have changes to my schema or new migration files, I run this command:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

Is there a prebuilt equivalent way to do this?

I thought from what I've read that `rake db:reset` doesn't quite do the same thing, but i could be wrong.

Comment: It’s rather excessive to do that every time a migration is added. Just `db:migrate` should be sufficient.

Comment: Except db:migrate doesn't run the seeds.

Comment: A new migration should not necessitate running seeds. Only changes to the seeds should require running seeds.

Comment: True, but i'm looking for a catch all. There's multiple developers on this project and every time i take an update, i just re create the db, and all it's migrations, seeds, etc.

Comment: Plus, if seeds get updated, i have to clear the db so that i don't have dupped seeds.

Comment: Maybe you should rewrite your seeds to be idempotent then.

Comment: How would i do that. What do most people do?

Comment: Check if the seed is already in the database. If it is, don't add it.

Comment: Alias "Yolo" in your bash profile to equal these commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could create a custom rake task for this - lib/tasks/db_rebuild_all.rake

```
namespace :db_tasks do
  desc "Rebuild database"
  task :rebuild, [] => :environment do
    raise "Not allowed to run on production" if Rails.env.production?

    Rake::Task['db:drop'].execute
    Rake::Task['db:create'].execute
    Rake::Task['db:migrate'].execute
    Rake::Task['db:seed'].execute
  end
end
```

then just run `bundle exec rake db_tasks:rebuild`

Comment: I spose i could do this, but if i was going to write a function to do this, i'd just create a unix alias which is much simpler.

Comment: an alias would work, but if you add this to your app then all developers have access to it; in the future you can add in steps to generate your db from a scrubbed production backup, etc...

Answer (score 4):

You could run `rake db:drop` and then `rake db:setup`.

`db:setup` will run `rake db:create db:schema:load and db:seed`

But why are you dropping and recreating your database everytime you have new migrations? That's what the migrations are there for, to make incremental changes to your existing database.

Comment: I'm dropping and recreating because if i changed a migration, it doesn't rerun it if it's already been run.

Comment: So does db:setup actually run the migrations?

Comment: db:setup will load whatever is in your schema.rb file, which if I remember correctly, is updated everytime you run a migration.

Comment: But the problem here is that the seeds that already exist, now get created again so we have dups.

Comment: You shouldn't change existing migrations after they've been deployed. Add a new migration.

Comment: I agree with @ctshryock. Also, if you're dropping your db every time, how are the seeds getting duplicated?

Comment: They don't if i drop the db. If i were to NOT drop the db, the seeds get dupped.

Comment: If your seeds file is changing that often, I'm not sure that there's an easier answer than to clear the db and reseed after your migrations run.

Answer (score 3):

> - Run `rake db:reset && rake db:seed` (Note: You must have db/schema.rb file updated) 
>     
>   **OR**
> - Run `rake db:migrate:reset && rake db:seed`

Comment: Note: `rake db:migrate:reset` reruns all the migrations from scratch, while `db:reset` simply regenerates the database based on the `schema.rb` file.

Answer (score 2):

As of rails 6 you can run `rake db:prepare` which creates the db, runs migrations and seeds

If you want to completely reset the db, run `rake db:drop && rake db:prepare`

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/6_0_release_notes.html#active-record-notable-changes

Answer (score 0):

First create the task file (lib/tasks/db.rake) with:

```
rails g task db reseed
```

Then write in it:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Reseed database task"
  task reseed: [ 'db:drop', 'db:create', 'db:migrate', 'db:seed' ] do
    puts 'Reseeding completed.'
  end
end
```